# Is there a way to atomically replace a stored function in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

The [MySQL manual on ALTER FUNCTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-function.html) says:

> However, you cannot change the parameters or body of a stored function using this statement; to make such changes, you must drop and re-create the function using DROP FUNCTION and CREATE FUNCTION.

The problem with using DROP + CREATE is that between the two statements, there will be a short time span in which the function does not exist. If this is a heavy duty database, this means that queries using the stored function will fail while executing in this timespan.

The [MySQL manual on implicit commits](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html) stresses that

> ALTER FUNCTION, CREATE FUNCTION and DROP FUNCTION also cause an implicit commit when used with stored functions

So it does not help to simply wrap the two problematic statements in a transaction.

PostgreSQL offers CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION for this. How does one solve the problem with MySQL?

Comment: I don't believe that this is possible.

Comment: I don't know what problem you are trying to solve, but constantly dropping and recreating a stored function in mysql is not the way to solve it.  I hope that this is just a "once in a while upgrade/maintenance" question.  If so, a transaction should do the job.  You also can table lock any relate tables using LOCK

Comment: @gview: A transaction does not work, see "it does not help to simply wrap the two problematic statements in a transaction" in my question, with explanation. LOCK does not work either because it will only prevent access to tables, not function execution. Sure it only happens once in a while, but it is a heavy duty database and I cannot afford to get an error for queries while the function does not exist for a short time span.

Comment: I guess I was not clear.  You would LOCK any tables that are worked on by the procedure or function.

Comment: @gview: That won't prevent invocation of the non-existing function or procedure either...

Comment: Who said it would?  It is protection against changes to the table(s) that would otherwise be effected by the procedure.  We don't know what your procedure(s) even do.

Answer (score 0):

Combining them in a transaction should solve the problem.  Remember that you must set autocommit = 0 at the start of the session before issuing a START TRANSACTION, and issue COMMIT at the end.

Comment: As I said in my question "it does not help to simply wrap the two problematic statements in a transaction". And BTW, [it is not necessary to set autocommit = 0 if you use START TRANSACTION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/commit.html)

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me:

```
MariaDB [test]> SELECT @@version;
+----------------+
| @@version      |
+----------------+
| 5.5.50-MariaDB |
+----------------+
```

proc.sql

```
use test;
START TRANSACTION;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS sproc;
delimiter //
CREATE PROCEDURE sproc(OUT param1 INT)
BEGIN
    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO param1 FROM t1;
END//
delimiter ;
COMMIT;

mysql -u root -p < proc.sql
mysql -u root -p < proc.sql
```

Inside mysql

```
MariaDB [test]> CALL sproc(@a);
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)

MariaDB [test]> select @a;
+------+
| @a   |
+------+
|    4 |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: This works, but not the way you think it does. Even though you start a transaction, the DROP and the CREATE implicitly commit any transaction that is currently going, so the actions are not atomic. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/implicit-commit.html

Comment: @Bill Karwin  Good to know.  Seems there is no solution for this problem that would satisfy the concerns of the question.

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not support CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION, or other feature to ensure atomicity of replacing the function. This has been an outstanding feature request since at least 2005: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=9588 There's no word on when they will implement this feature, if ever.

For what it's worth, the feature of CREATE OR REPLACE is not standard SQL. It's an extension to standard SQL, which PostgreSQL decided to implement.

One workaround might be to define the new function with a different name, so both the old and the new function exist for a short time. Your application code (or code in other MySQL routines) would need to be designed to call the new function name dynamically.